# Синтаксическое значение (синтаксические отношения) в предложении

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

> Князь Андрей, думавший, что ему было все равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск, внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.

Отношения являются объектными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, здесь объектные отношения. Такие придаточные всегда в основном связаны с глаголами речи-мысли: говорить, сказать, ответить, думать, решить, заключить, прийти к выводу, предположить и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении два типа отношений:

1) объектные, связанные с семантикой опорных слов "думал". "всё равно";

2) атрибутивные (признаковые, определительные), связанные с раскрытием содержания наречного (адвербиального) коррелята КАК в придаточном предложении.